# PHP create value variable for json_encode function

Tags: php, json, encode

I'm using a JSON API; I want to create a variable with values and then convert it to a JSON string via `json_encode`. The (working) JSON string is this:

```
$data = '
{
"function":"setArticleImages",
"paras":{
    "user":"'.$user.'",
    "pass":"'.$pass.'",
    "product_model":"'.$productsModel.'",
    "images":{
        "products_id":'.$products_id.',
        "image_name":"'.$imageName.'",
        "image":"'.$image.'",
        "products_images":[{
                "products_id":'.$products_id.',
                "image_name":"'.$imageName2.'",
                "image":"'.$image2.'"
            }        ]
    }
}}
';
```

I was now trying to write it like this and use `json_encode`:

```
$data = array(
    "function" => "setArticleImages",
    "paras" => array(
        "user" => $user,
        "pass" => $pass,
        "product_model" => $productsModel,
        "images" => array(
            "products_id" => $products_id,
            "image_name" => $imageName,
            "image" => $image,
            "products_images" => array(
                "products_id" => $products_id,
                "image_name" => $imageName2,
                "image" => $image2,
            ),
        )
    )
);
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Unfortunately it does not work. The problems seems to be at `'"products_images" => array('`. I don't know how to handle the `'['` of the  `'"products_images":[{'` part.

Anyone an idea how to write it in the second code snippet?

Comment: It does not work __how__?

Comment: Not sure what error you are getting, echo $data and check if JSON is made correctly, you can use jsonlint.com to validate your JSON. By the way, I tried to put dummy values in your code and it seems like working, I can see the correct JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add an extra level of array to the `products_images` element, so that you get a numerically indexed array of associative arrays, giving you the array of objects form you want:

```
$data = array(
    "function" => "setArticleImages",
    "paras" => array(
        "user" => $user,
        "pass" => $pass,
        "product_model" => $productsModel,
        "images" => array(
            "products_id" => $products_id,
            "image_name" => $imageName,
            "image" => $image,
            "products_images" => array(
                array(
                    "products_id" => $products_id,
                    "image_name" => $imageName2,
                    "image" => $image2,
                )
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fon4Y)

Answer (score 0):

The "{ }" in th JSON notation is a PHP array with alphanumerical key.

So :

```
$array = ["foo" => [1,2,3], "bar" => [4,5,6]
```

will be converted in a JSON string :

```
{ foo : [1,2,3], bar: [4,5,6]}
```

So if you are looking to a JSON that looks like this

```
[{ foo : [1,2,3], bar: [4,5,6]}]
```

You will have to do an array with numeric keys that contains your alphanumerical array :

```
$array = [["foo" => [1,2,3], "bar" => [4,5,6]]];
// same as
$array = [ 0 => ["foo" => [1,2,3], "bar" => [4,5,6]]];
```